# ListView with multicolumn and color

Tags: android, listview, textview, multiple-columns

I want to build a `ListView` in Android. It should have `multiple coloums` and the possibility to `change color of only some rows`. I have tried this, but i think it calls **toString()** of the LinearLayout. I dont get the `text inside the TextView`. I've tried in days. Please help. 
The code below is just experimentation for the real project.

```
public class EventActivity extends ListActivity {


List<Event> events2;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.event_layout);    




    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listEvents);
    listView = getListView();

    TextView t1 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    TextView t2 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    TextView t3 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    TextView t4 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    TextView t5 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    TextView t6 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    TextView t7 = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    t1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    t2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    t3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    t4.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    t5.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    t6.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    t1.setText("1111");         
    t2.setText("2111");
    t3.setText("3111");
    t4.setText("4111");         
    t5.setText("5111");
    t6.setText("6111");         
    t7.setText("7111");
    t1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    t4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
            LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.addView(t1);
    ll.addView(t2);
    ll.addView(t3);
    ll.addView(t4);     
    ll.addView(t5);
    ll.addView(t6);
    ll.addView(t7);

    ArrayList<LinearLayout> lllist = new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();

    lllist.add(ll);

    ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout> eventAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout>(EventActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,lllist );


    listView.setAdapter(eventAdapter);
```

Comment: check this http://www.technotalkative.com/android-multi-column-listview/

Comment: this ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listEvents);
    listView = getListView(); is already a problem. make up your mind. use either the listView from the listActivity or one with your own id, but both is conterproductive at best

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it looks like you want to make a ListView that displays: "1111", "2111", etc.  Here is a simple way to do this *and* change each row's color according to its index:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String[] array = new String[] {"1111", "2111", "3111", "4111", "5111", "6111"};
        ColorfulArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ColorfulArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public class ColorfulArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
        public ColorfulArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects) {
            // There are many more constructors available from ArrayAdapter, consult the documentation for specifics!
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            // Change the background from its position, I added three choices
            switch(position % 3) {
            case 0: // Red
                view.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
                break;
            case 1: // Green
                view.setBackgroundColor(0xff00ff00);
                break;
            case 2: // Blue
                view.setBackgroundColor(0xff0000ff);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Changing this example for multiple columns is easy enough, you simply need start with an object that has more than one piece member data, chose the appropriate adapter and specify what columns go where. For instance:

- A SimpleCursorAdapter binds data from a SQLite query.
- A SimpleAdapter binds data from generic Map objects.
- You can always write your own adapter to try to maximize efficiency.

Hope that helps getting you started!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Custom List Adapter for your requirement.

**Step1**

Intialize your ListView

**Step 2**

Call the Adapter using

```
MultiColumnAdapter review = new MultiColumnAdapter(this,logDetails_cursor);
listview.setAdapter(review);
```

**Step 3**

MultiColumnAdapter

```
 class MultiColumnAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;

    RequestLogAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

         //Get your details here
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
                    //Create xml for multicolumnlistview
        return mInflater.inflate(R.layout.mulitcolumnlistview, parent, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
                    //Rows of multicolumn listview
        TextView reqdate = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.firstcolumn);
        TextView reqtime = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.secondcolumn);
        TextView reqfromlocation = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.thirdcolumn);

        String text1 = cursor.getString(i_requestdate);
        reqdate.setText(yourtext);

        String text2 = cursor.getString(i_requesttime);
        reqtime.setText(timeRequested);

        String text3 = cursor.getString(i_requestfromlocation);
        reqfromlocation.setText(yourtext);

       }
     }
```

mulitcolumnlistview ListView Xml

You can set background color here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:paddingTop="4dip"
 android:paddingBottom="6dip"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

 <TextView android:id="@+id/column1"
     android:layout_width="70dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:textColor="@color/White" 
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
     android:layout_weight="1" 
     android:textSize="16sp" />

 <TextView android:id="@+id/column2"
     android:layout_width="60dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:layout_weight="1" 
     android:textSize="16sp" 
     android:textColor="@color/White"   
     android:maxLines="1" />  

 <TextView android:id="@+id/column3"
     android:layout_width="50dip"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
     android:textSize="17sp"  
     android:textColor="@color/White"  
     android:layout_weight="2" />
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Your custom adapter is unnecessary, it is less efficient than SimpleCursorAdapter and your Java R.id references don't match your XML id's... If you only want to pass a custom layout use this `new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.multicolumnlistview, cursor, new String[] { i_requestdate, i_requesttime, i_requestfromlocation }, new int[] { R.id.column1, R.id.column2, R.id.column3 });` Also you neglected to change the color of any rows...

Comment: I'm specially interested in changing the color. That was my actually problem. Do you have an example on changing the color of a row. The text color can vary. A row can be declined, accepted or pending. So i have to set the color of the rows, depending of the row status.